# How to create symlink for storage public folder for Lumen

Tags: php, storage, lumen

I have used the following command to create symnlink for storage public folder for my project which I'm doing in  Lumen .
=> php artisan storage:link

But I am getting this error in terminal =>

There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.

Another query is though I'm able to upload file in storage folder , how I'm able to access,  I need some sample code for this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created  by this unix command :

ln -s sourceforwhich symnlinkfolderpath
e.g.:

ln -s /data/html/projectfolder/storage/app/public /data/html/projectfolder/public/storage

Answer (score 6):

This is for windows,

First of all run `cmd` with administrator if you are on another user not in admin and then go to your project's public path e.g. `project/path/public`.

Then run below command,

`mklink /D "storage\" "E:absolute/static/path~/storage/app/public/"`

For e.g.,

`mklink /D "storage\" "E:/User Name/Work/My Projects/storage/app/public/"`

Hopefully it will help for Lumen windows users.

Answer (score 4):

More simple and short way using unix command :

Go to the lumen/public folder in the terminal or via ssh etc.

Run :

```
ln -s ../storage/app/public storage
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Lumen 8.0 on Mac and Linux machine. I did not find any solution for lumen but we can create symbolic link by using full/complete path in command line:

```
ln -s /var/www/storage/app /var/www/public/storage
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thank you very much to ask this question.

Comment: I am just appreciating question owner, why are you trying to restricting me? I am not doing any wrong thing or using any abuse words for any one then why do you changing my answer again and again? Is this .... your nature?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, running below command in a Lumen project folder simply helps:

```
mklink /J public\storage storage\app\public
```

It does not require any Administrator privileges.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lumen's artisan doesn't support "storage", that's why you got an error. Try to upload your file to app/public folder instead.

Change your upload path to app/public, too.