# Not playable audio file stored in laravel lumen

Tags: laravel, storage, lumen

I have a mp3 audio file stored in `public/storage` folder which is linked from `storage/app/public` folder, simulating the `php artisan storage:link` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990932/6459968) command.

So, now I can access directly in the browser like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view) doing `http://my-domain/storage/example.mp3` in my browser. I get the audio, but isn't playable, I don't know why.

When I type `http://my-domain/storage/example.mp3` in my browser I get this:

[image]

**The audio isn't corrupted** because I tried to move it manually from it's path `public/storage` (with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/lang:es)) to my window's desktop and it plays normal. I don't know what's happening with this. Can someone help me?

**Edit:** I also tried to make a get route to play the audio, so I did something like this:

```
public function getAudio(Request $request, $filename){

    if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists($filename)){
           return "error";
    } 
    try {
       $type = Storage::mimeType($filename);
       $file = Storage::get($filename);

       return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', $type);

    } catch (\Exception $e){
       return $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

But I'm getting the same as the screenshot...

**Edit:** It only happens with **audio files**, with .txt files it shows me the file content and also with images, works fine.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? I guess it serves the wrong mine type

Comment: There isn't any error. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the mp3 file, I don't know about formats but I used `ffmpeg` from [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), to convert the audio file to `.ogg` and it worked. I'm still confused why the mp3 file wasn't playable.